# Serialization Of Arrays in Java

Tags: java, serialization

I would like to serialize my Employee class and all its member variables. Everything works fine but I am unable retrieve the array phone numbers.

I am able to deserialize rest of the attributes however when i try to fetch the "List Phone" using the getter method i am not able see the list values.Please suggest the right approach to deserialize and retrieve the list.

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -368639392869464826L;
    private int employeeId;
    private String employeeName;
    private String department;
    private Address address;



    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }

    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
}

public class Address implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3239980378124981113L;
    private int slno;  
    private String street;  
    private String city; 
    private List<Phone> number;

    public Address(int slno, String street, String city, List<Phone> number) {
        super();
        this.slno = slno;
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
        this.number = number;
    }
    public int getHomeNo() {
        return slno;
    }
    public void setHomeNo(int slno) {
        this.slno = slno;
    }
    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }
    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public List<Phone> getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(List<Phone> number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

}

public class Phone implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3875860424349502485L;
    private int number;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }


}

public class SerializeMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Phone> phone = new ArrayList<Phone>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Phone ph = new Phone();
            ph.setNumber(i);
            phone.add(ph);
        }

        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setEmployeeId(101);
        emp.setEmployeeName("Raghu");
        emp.setDepartment("ECE");
        Address address = new Address(88, "MG road", "Pune", phone);
        emp.setAddress(address);

        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("F:\\test.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            outStream.writeObject(emp);
            outStream.close();
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }

        Employee emp1 = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("F:\\test.txt");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            emp1 = (Employee) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
            System.out.println("Employee class not found");
            c.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Deserialized Employee...");
        System.out.println("Emp id: " + emp1.getEmployeeId());
        System.out.println("Name: " + emp1.getEmployeeName());
        System.out.println("Department: " + emp1.getDepartment());
        for(Phone num:emp1.getAddress().getNumber()){
             System.out.println("Address " + num);
         }

    }

}
```

---

Output:

```
Emp id: 101
Name: Raghu
Department: ECE
Address [com.raghu.test.Phone@1d44bcfa, com.raghu.test.Phone@266474c2, com.raghu.test.Phone@6f94fa3e, com.raghu.test.Phone@5e481248, com.raghu.test.Phone@66d3c617, com.raghu.test.Phone@63947c6b, com.raghu.test.Phone@2b193f2d, com.raghu.test.Phone@355da254, com.raghu.test.Phone@4dc63996, com.raghu.test.Phone@d716361]
```

Comment: You need to serialize the phone number: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javaserial-1536170.html

Answer (score 3):

One thing you could do is override toString() to the Phone class, for example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {         
    return "Phone{number=" + number + "}";     
}
```

Comment: @RaghuChaitanya please mark question  as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

When you do `emp1.getAddress().getNumber()` it returns a List of numbers; It's printing the List object. You have to iterate through the List to print the numbers;

```
List<Phone> l=emp.getAddress().getNumber();
for(Phone p:l)
{
 System.out.println(p.getNumber());
}
```

Comment: Hi @underdog .I have tried Doing that    using the below loop but it dosent seem to work                                                                  for(Phone num:emp1.getAddress().getNumber()){
    System.out.println("Address " + num); 
   }

Comment: It works for me; I am getting the output; You have to to do System.out.println("Address " + num.getNumber());

Comment: No, the list object should already have a well-defined `toString` method.  What you're seeing is the result of not having a `toString` defined on `Phone`.

Comment: @Makoto ya I concur overriding toString() is the correct way to do this